# Bundler::GemNotFound Error

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm using Ubuntu. I tried installing bundler via 'gem install bundler', and it seems to have worked. In terminal, if I type 'gem list', I see bundler 1.3.5 in the list. However, if I run 'bundle install', I get the error 'Bundler::GemfileNotFound'... I'm not sure why

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the bundle binary is not in your path.

You can check this by executing the following:

```
     echo $PATH
     which bundle
```

If your bundle path is: /Users/xxx/.rbenv/shims/bundle

Your PATH needs to include: /Users/xxx/.rbenv/shims

https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path

Comment: Bonus for ref'ing rbenv

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there's nothing wrong with my path as far as I can tell: $PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/me/.rvm/bin

and which bundle returns /usr/local/bin/bundle, and that's in my path, right?

Answer (score 0):

Bundler is looking for a file called `Gemfile` in your current directory. The error means that it isn't there. Are you sure you're in the right directory?